# Is there a way to set a specific amount of maximum spaces for TAB character (backslash t) "\t" in C++?

Tags: c++, tabs, char, cout

I want to print a square matrix that needs to be spaced each between the elements by 3 spaces. Then I found that char `'\t'` might be the easiest way. But, I think the number of spaces is somehow defined in certain algorithm. Could someone give me a guide through the algorithm or is there a way to set certain spaces in C++ for `'\t'`?

I know how to output manually by determining the number of space character. However `'\t'` seems simple to code rather than looping certain algorithm.

For a simple square matrix :

```
for (int x = 0, num = 1; x < 5; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++, num++) {
            cout << num << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

The code outputs

```
1       2       3       4       5
6       7       8       9       10
11      12      13      14      15
16      17      18      19      20
21      22      23      24      25
```

while I need

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25
```

Is there a way to set '\t'?

Comment: The tab width is governed by the console. To ensure consistent and deterministic spacing, don't use the `\t` character at all. Make use of the [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) steam manipulator instead

Comment: The number of spaces in a TAB is actually defined by the output thing. In text editors, I often saw an option for that. In a shell (like e.g. `bash`) I'm not sure whether it's configurable nor what role plays the terminal. The actual width of a TAB is something very unreliable. May be, you investigate alternatively into `<iomanip>`, [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw), etc.

Comment: Thanks for bits of advice! I'll consider to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, I think the number of spaces is somehow defined in certain algorithm.
>   ...
>   Is there a way to set `'\t'`?

Not unless your connected terminal allows you to control that in a way.

The usual way to control output formatting using [I/O manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), for your case

- `std::setw()`
- `std::left` (or may be better `std::right` for numbers)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the size of a tab is defined by your console, so this will be a setting of your IDE.
If you want a consistent quantity of spaces, you're better off using spaces. That way you don't have to alter the console  settings of everything you run your code on. Why not just do something like

```
"    "
```

instead of "\t" ?

EDIT: Apparently Stack overflow doesn't appreciate multiple spaces in-text.

Comment: I have done the thing this way which prints a certain number of spaces, but I prefer something like function or else.